# Using a select list to toggle a div's visibility

Tags: jquery, select, toggle, show, show-hide

I have a select list:

```
<select id="cd-dropdown" class="cd-select">
<option value="-1" selected>Menu</option>
<option value="http://google.com" class="home">1</option>
    <option value="http://google.com" class="home">2</option>
</select>
```

I also have an div that will overlay the entire screen when the select list is tapped or clicked (underneath the options):

```
<div class="overlay"></div>
```

Using jQuery I'd like to show/hide this overlay depending on the state the select is in. So if I open the select list, I want the overlay div to fade in and when the select list is closed or an option is selected I'd like the overlay to fade out.

I cannot get my jQuery to work:

```
$('#cd-dropdown').onchange( function() {
    $( '#overlay' ).toggle.fadeIn();
    $( '#overlay' ).toggle.fadeOut();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `.change()` for the binding, instead of `.onchange()`. Also remove `.toggle`, just use `.fadeIn()` or `.fadeOut()`.

EDIT: I added a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/goffreder/mmbYg/1/) to explain better. You probably should detect the `onfocus` event to fade in the overlay, and the `onblur` event to fade it out. Something like this:

```
$("#cd-dropdown").change(function(event) {
    $("#cd-dropdown").blur();
}).focus(function() {
    $(".overlay").fadeIn();
}).blur(function() {
    $(".overlay").fadeOut();
});
```

Comment: Thats great! Thanks! This might fall under another question but how could I adapt this to work for an unordered list?

Comment: The list is the element that has to fade in/out or is used to make a selection?

Comment: Same functionality as above question but the list is the element that has to make the selection

Comment: I'm assuming you want the overlay to fade out if there is any option selected and to fade in if there isn't a selection. I made a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/goffreder/K5aAv/) for testing

Comment: Yeah thats correct, I've tried implementing here but can't seem to hide the overlay when the list item isn't selected? http://jsfiddle.net/K5aAv/1/

Comment: You can check if there are any selected element, if `$(".selected").size()` is equal to 0, `$(".overlay").fadeOut()`

Comment: You need to wrap `$(".selected").size() == 0` with parenthesis, and you have to put the entire `if` inside the `click` handler, so it is checked every time a click on the list happens. See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/goffreder/K5aAv/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('#overlay').fadeToggle();
```

Or, to be more precise,

```
$('#cd-dropdown').onchange( function() {
     if($('#cd-dropdown').value == 1)
         $('#overlay').fadeIn();
     else if($('#cd-dropdown').value == 2)
         $('#overlay').fadeOut();
}
```

Comment: Not ideal as I'd have to keep extending the script for more and more options. Ideally I'd like something that is generic enough to match all options in the select list